# PHP: Load a list of plugins/modules dynamically

Tags: php, oop, plugins

In my project I'm processing data and working with the results. There is an abstract class which looks like the following:

```
class AbstractInterpreter
{
    public function interprete( $data )
    {
        throw new Exception('Abstract Parent, nothing implemented here');
    }
}
```

And then there are various different implementations of the `AbstractInterpreter`:

```
class FooInterpreter extends AbstractInterpreter
{
    public function interprete( $data )
    {
        return "resultFoo";
    }
}
class BarInterpreter extends AbstractInterpreter
{
    public function interprete( $data )
    {
        return "resultBar";
    }
}
```

My calling code creates the interpreters and collects the results:

```
//this is the data we're working with
$data = "AnyData";

//create the interpreters
$interpreters = array();
$foo = new FooInterpreter();
$bar = new BarInterpreter();
$interpreters[] = $foo;
$interpreters[] = $bar;

//collect the results
$results = array();
foreach ($interpreters as $currentInterpreter)
{
    $results[] = $currentInterpreter->interprete($data);
}
```

I'm currently creating more and more interpreters and the code gets messy... For each interpreter I need to add a certain `include_once(..)` and I have to instantiate it and put it into the `$interpreters`.

**Now, to finally ask my question:**
*Is it possible to automatically include and instantiate all interpreters that are in a specific directory and put them into the `$interpreters`?*

In other languages this would be some kind of a plugin-concept:
I create different implementations of `AbstractInterpreter`, put them in a specific subdirectory and the software uses them automatically. I would not have to modify the code which loads the interpreters as soon as it is finished.

Comment: It looks like someone has some Java history.  `$currentInterpreter.interprete($data);` should be `$currentInterpreter->interprete($data);`.  Why not use an interface instead of a class with defined methods that throw exceptions?  Interfaces in PHP are analogous to Java abstracts.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: It's C++, but it was a good guess ;)
I will have a look into PHP interfaces, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible automatically, but you can write a few lines code to get the same result.

```
function includeInterpreters($path) {

    $interpreters=array();

    if ($dh = opendir($path)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

            include_once($path.$file);
            $fileNameParts=explode('.', $file);
            $interpreters[]=new $fileNameParts[0];

        }
        closedir($dh);
    }

    return $interpreters;
}

$interpreters= includeInterpreters('/path/plugins');
```

Name your class files as InterpreterName.php and put into the same directory, for example plugings

And yes, this looks messy.

Comment: I'm not a PHP-native speaker, so pardon my question: Isn't `$fileNameParts[0]` a string? Is it possible to instantiate a class from a string? If so, that would make the implementation of such a system quite easy, as your code states.

Comment: @Muatik I'd enclose that in curly braces.  I can't really try it now, but I think the way you did it would not work, but interpolating the variable by enclosing it in curly braces would.

Comment: As a C++ programmer this is pure magic :D Thanks a lot! I'll wait a few days if there are other opinions/answers coming up. Then I'll mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: $fileNameParts[0] represents the name of class and php can instance from this class. I have tried.

Comment: Just implemented it that way (there were some smaller changes necessary, like checking for "." and ".."), everything works great!